# How to use leaflet-overpass-layer plugins?

Tags: plugins, leaflet, overpass-api

I've been trying to query overpass on leaflet map with no result with those plugins

- https://github.com/GuillaumeAmat/leaflet-overpass-layer
- https://github.com/kartenkarsten/leaflet-layer-overpass

but honestly I have no idea if I even did it right. I opened the demo code locally but nothing happened. Should I be running it on server? Should I download any of the folders?

I would appreciate it if someone told me what to do step by step to use those plugins, I am a total newbie...

Comment: There's an example implementation on the readme page for both of those plugins. What happened when you followed it? Where's your code?

Comment: What I did was copying the demo from demo folder and opening it locally, but all I got was the map and no query result. Then I tried to also copy the OverPassLayer.css and  OverPassLayer.bundle.js from dist folder and referencing them locally with also with no result. Then, since I am using codio a bit, I tried to open it on server while installing the plug in (no idea if I did it right) by typing npm install leaflet-overpass-layer, and again nothing other than the map. It may seem silly, but I have no idea what I am doing, that's why I'm trying to ask for help

Comment: The only code I used was taken from the plugins' demos and such, so I don't know if there's a meaning in posting it in here, I literally just copied what was there